# Unresolved import: webbrowser

Tags: python, aptana, python-webbrowser

When I run the code below in Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.0.9.201202141038 on my iMac running OS X 10.6(Snowleopard) I get the error below.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('http://google.com')


Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/Users/gianl/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Thought Log 3 w
dropbox/src/webbrowser.py", line 1, in <module>
    import webbrowser   File "/Users/gianl/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Thought Log 3 w dropbox/src/webbrowser.py", line 3, in
<module>
    webbrowser.open('http://google.com') AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open'
```

Why am I getting this error in Aptana when I do not get this error in terminal?

Answer (score 6):

You named your file `webbrowser.py`. It shadows the real `webbrowser` module and imports itself.

Change your filename and remove the `webbrowser.pyc` that is also in the same directory and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change the name of your python script from webbrowser.py to something like my_web_browser.py. I don;t know why it does that, my guess is that might be a pointer issue.

Comment: This really needed to be a comment rather then answer as you are guessing.

Answer (score 0):

RENAME YOUR .PY FILE .. MAKE SURE THAT IS NOT webbrowser.py ... you can name it anything
if you are importing webbrowser then you can't save your file as webbrowser.py
if you are importing requests
then you can't name you file name as request.py

in shot never name you file as imported module name.. yes you can type my_request.py or my_webbrowser.py GOOD LUCK